# Linkedin Code Sample returning Null User object

Tags: linkedin-api

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples

Using the above PHP code sample, I can log in to my user profile as expected, (after creating the required "application" and getting the API KEY and SECRET, of course.)

However the $user object returned by the Fetch() function is null, so I do not have access to the profile content via the code, such as the $user->firstname and $user->lastname, etc.

FYI: This question was asked before and not answered:
[LinkedIn Code Sample not returning ay data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390291)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I found was that file_get_contents() was not working, and this was because allow_url_fopen was not enabled in PHP.ini. I believe allow_url_fopen is not enabled by default, as it is a security issue. I found a work-around online using cUrl. See the code below.

//First, in getAccessToken() replace 
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context) 
with 
$response = curl_get_contents($url);

Than add the following function to the code sample.

```
function curl_get_contents($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```